# How to return all objects where a string is matching?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

i'am searching a way to solve this problem , I just modified the return of the rest API search endpoint in Wordpress, in order to get a specific format of object.

```
public function custom_api_search_posts_callback(WP_REST_REQUEST $request)
    {
        // Initialize the array that will receive the posts' data. 
        $posts_data = [];
        // Receive and set the page parameter from the $request for pagination purposes
        $paged = $request->get_param('page');
        $paged = (isset($paged) || !(empty($paged))) ? $paged : 1;
        $posts = get_posts([
            'paged' => $paged,
            'post__not_in' => get_option('sticky_posts'),
            'posts_per_page' => 300,
            'post_type' => ['pizzas', 'tagliate', 'les_antipasti', 'la_carne', 'ptes_et_risottos', 'les_desserts', 'les_boissons', 'vins', 'les_cocktails', 'cichetteria'] // This is the line that allows to fetch multiple post types. 
        ]);
        // Loop through the posts and push the desired data to the array we've initialized earlier in the form of an object
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $id = $post->ID;
            $meta = get_post_meta($id);
            $search = 'calz';

            $posts_data[] = (object)[
                'id' => $id,
                'type' => get_post_type_object($post->post_type)->labels->name,
                'slug' => $post->post_type,
                'content' => ['rendered' => $post->post_content],
                'title' => ['rendered' => $post->post_title],
                'categories' => $this->transformCategory($id),
                'meta' => $this->transformMeta($id),
            ];
        }
//here i would like to get all the object matching the search
enter code here
        foreach ($posts_data as $key => $element) {
            if (stristr($element->title['rendered'], $search) !== false) {
                return $posts_data[$key];
//with stristr it returns only the first result
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're `return`ing after the first 'match'. You should build a results array that collects all matches and when the `foreach` has finished going through all the posts, return the results `$results`:

```
...

   foreach ($posts_data as $key => $element) {
        if (stristr($element->title['rendered'], $search) !== false) {
            // return $posts_data[$key];
            $results[] = $posts_data[$key];
           //with stristr it returns only the first result
        }
    }
return $results;
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot, i use to do js most of the time , i get blocked for over two hours searching an equivalent of array.filter in php :-)

Comment: Glad I could help!